# What's Kotlin's compatibility policy?

Tags: kotlin

Once Kotlin 1.0 is out, what will be the compatibility policy? As a user, I hope Kotlin would keep its compatibility, either in source or binary. Just as serious as Java.

On contrast, Scala is a bad example. Failing to keep its binary compatibility between minor versions drove me away. And I believe a lot of users have left Scala partly because of its compatibility issue. This caused many libraries (including SBT at my time) cannot provide a complete suite of distributions for the whole series of Scala versions. This is just binary compatibility issue. Imagine if source compatibility was broken.

I have decided to use Kotlin in my company's commercial project. So I really need to be sure Kotlin is **serious** about keeping compatibility, instead of pursuing beauty.

Comment: I'm worried about this because I have seen a lot language constructs like "trait" have changed since the milestone releases.

Comment: I'm voting this down - not because I am not interested in the answer or that I dislike the question. I do however think that the only authoritative source will be the Kotlin web-page, and the answer can only quote from there. Given that the answer may also change in time, repeating it here does not make much sense.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I disagree. Because Jetbrains is watching this tag. It's reasonable to ask this question here. In fact my previous questions about Kotlin were mostly if not all, anwsered by Jetbrains guys. Also compatibility policy is not something that's going to change in time. Once it's done it's done. So I think it's better to let everyone know it here.

Comment: Good point, although the answer still seems to be directly from Kotlin's site. Let me change some things around

Comment: This is a bad question, if he was reading Kotlin blogs and public information he would have seen it noted in the beta 1 announcement, and the beta 4 announcement with complete clarity the plan for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Oh really? Like I should be watching kotlin blog every f**king day? Google "kotlin compatibility policy" yourself, see what is the first item. And try to find the blog in the first page, then come back here to say this is a bad question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kotlin isn't out yet (UPD: [now it is](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/02/kotlin-1-0-released-pragmatic-language-for-jvm-and-android/)). Changes to the language are to be expected (even changes that break code and binary compatibility).

With the Beta release the binary format was finalized, so we shouldn't expect changes there anymore (but they might still happen if bugs have to be fixed).

After 1.0 gets released the language and the binary format is supposed to be backwards compatible forever.

Source: http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/11/the-kotlin-language-1-0-beta-is-here/

Comment: You can see the official strategy laid out nicely in this blog post for Beta 4 in the "What’s next" section:  http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/12/kotlin-1-0-beta-4-is-out/  ... binary compatibility post 1.0 is the short answer.  And 1.0 is very soon.

Comment: Where does the source say the "forever" part? I wonder if they'll break binary compatibility (like Scala) in Kotlin 2.0 for example.

Comment: Just noticed [this comment](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/12/kotlin-1-0-beta-4-is-out/#comment-41068) that says breaking changes (if any) will happen very slowly.